# How to overwrite If a file or directory exist?

Tags: shell

I tried this code but errors is there, What changes do I need to make to get the desired behavior? 
my requirement is create a new Directory(Folder) 
Directory exist then overwrite the Directory, if a Directory doesn't exist create a new Directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
Directory=$1

if [ -d "$Directory" ]; then
    echo "Directory $Directory exist. Do you want overwrite it? (y/n)" 
    read yn                                              
    if [ $yn = "N" -o $yn = "n"];
    then
        exit 0
    fi
    cp -fR  /home/task/$Directory  /home/task/directory
else
    echo "Directory Does not exist"      
    mkdir -p $Directory
fi
```

changes is there anyone

Comment: doing `echo "HELLO" > filename` will create new file if it does not exist, else it will overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not commenting on the rest of your code but to get rid of the syntax error you need to have whitespace around brackets:

```
if [ $yn = "N" -o $yn = "n"];
                           ^---- this needs a space here
```